# Help confirming this TJI joist can span an opening

Tags: joists, span-tables, tji

I have an interior wall that I'm going to be cutting an opening in. the top plate is a TJI joist. I'm 95% certain it's 20in, but it is definitely at least an 18in (see pic).

Underneath the joist is a standard wall with studs at 16in oc. Ignore the water lines as I will be shifting them.

[image]

The highlighted portion is where I want to cut the opening. It's ~88in.

The specs I found for the joists are here:

[Specs](https://www.millcreeklumber.com/clientcontent/mcl/pdf/TJ-4000.pdf)

Obviously the studs on the left under the edge cannot be removed as that is where the joist ends. And im asking about the span because I would prefer to not have a header and let the opening extend as high as possible for asthetic reasons.

This joist has another interior wall sitting on top of it. On the far side it has joist hangers for joists that extend over the garage. The near side has joist hangers for the joists over the living room.

From what I can tell these joists can *easily* make that span without needing any sort of header underneath, based on page 18 of the spec document. However there is *alot* of information there and I want to be certain I'm interpreting it right.

Comment: As long as the there are no point loads like a single column or a load bearing wall running perpendicular to the beam, you would convert all of the tributary areas to a pounds per foot load along the 20" beam. Call it "w". For a beam of length "L", the end reactions and maximum shear are wL/2, the required "maximum resistive moment" is wL²/8, and the maximum deflection is L/360. See page 16 of your "specs" document.